# DocumentSpec does not contain a definition for TypeMetadata and no extension method TypeMetadata accepting a first argument of type DocumentSpec coul

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error . Can you please help me how to get rid of this error.

[image]

> 'DocumentSpec' does not contain a definition for 'TypeMetadata' and no
>   extension method 'TypeMetadata' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DocumentSpec' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: Please provide exception detail as text to your question.

Comment: 'DocumentSpec' does not contain a definition for 'TypeMetadata' and no extension method 'TypeMetadata' accepting a first argument of type 'DocumentSpec' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)